# Controller 'ng-model', required by directive 'ngModel', can't be found! in custom validation directive

Tags: angularjs, customvalidator, dynamic-html

I am writing a page which shows a input form which is dynamically created by the data from the database.

I am building the dynamic html & rendering it into the main page using a custom directive called "dynamic-render". It is successfully rendered.

I also have validation for the input fields in the dynamically created form. The default validations like required are working fine.

I also have custom validation directives in the dynamic form. But it is not working.

I am getting "Controller 'ng-model', required by directive 'ngModel', can't be found!" error.

I have googled & tried the solutions but none helped me.

I have created a demo in plunk.
[Plunk Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/59clrq)

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: It's `require: "ngModel"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You should write it with a [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase):

```
require: "ngModel"
```

---

From [directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Angular **normalizes** an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) **normalized** name (e.g. *ngModel*). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The **normalization** process is as follows:
>
> - Strip *x-* and *data-* from the front of the element/attributes.
> - Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.